# Drupal 7 customizing the field in add content in admin panel

Tags: drupal

http://www.photouploads.com/images/customfiel.jpg

i have configure a taxonomy as field of a content type, but i want to replace the checkbox label(work with iphone) to an image which is a image field of that taxonomy(see the photo).

At now i only know to alter node.pages.inc at row 290 by add the code:

```
$form['product_label'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => 'Checkboxes Title',
    '#title_display' => 'before',
    '#default_value' => array(0,2),
    '#options' => array(
      0 => 'option one',
      1 => 'option two',
      2 => 'option three', 
    ), 
    '#theme' => 'testmodule_checkboxes',
  );
```

the product_label is the checkbox name, the above code is to override the current checkbox field. But i think this a not a best way to do.. 
anyone can provide direction to me? what module or coding can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You shouldn't hack core (except in very few edge cases if you really know what you're doing).](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core)

The best place to do this is in your theme. In `template.php`, you need to use the [hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7), [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to alter that specific form. You can find out more about the FAPI (form API) [here](http://drupal.org/node/751826) and [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

There's a few ways to alter the form to get the result you want. The easiest way would be to add a unique class for each icon to each form item's [attributes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) array. You can then use CSS to [replace the text](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/) with the icon (this makes it more accessible as screen readers will still be able to read the text).